# meteor 1.4 buildpack for bluemix

Tags: meteor, ibm-cloud, buildpack

The available build pack fails for meteor 1.4 https://github.com/ind1go/bluemix-buildpack-meteor.

Is there any working build pack for meteor 1.4 to deploy to bluemix? or please guide with alternative ways.

Answer (score 0):

As of late August 2016, I have had success with deploying Meteor 1.4.1 on Bluemix utilizing this buildpack:

https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse

Some additional details in this PR:

https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse/pull/130

Meteor is changing rapidly, and application packages and project configuration may define your ability to be successful with this buildpack.